# Passing a mock DOM event to component method in Angular for unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a method in one of my components as follows:

```
toggle(event: Event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
}
```

I cannot find a way to pass the event object to the method in the unit test case for example:

```
test('it should call stop propagation when toggled', () => {
    testHostComponent.toggleLineBreakDown(mockEventGoesHere, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can test that preventDefault has been called via a Jasmine Spy.

You will have to create the event you are listening to, before using the SpyOn method. (In the following example it's a 'click' event). After creating the event and the spy, you will then need to dispatch the event to the element.

As an example:

```
const event = new MouseEvent('click'); 
spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');

element.dispatchEvent(event);
expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton, it saved me a lot of hassle